# Saxon xslt transformation is adding system properties to output

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I am using Saxon HE and using it from command line. I am using the command mentioned in the documentation as

```
java net.sf.saxon.Transform -s:source -xsl:stylesheet -o:output
```

The transformation is working absolutely fine, except that the output file contains the list of all the java system properties before the actual content. I don't think I have anything special in my xslt. I am copying the first few lines here.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/java/object/void[@property='testResults']">
<testsuites>
```

Is there any clue why this could be happening?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


java.vm.version
24.75-b04


isWindowsPlatform
false


sun.jnu.encoding
UTF-8


java.vendor.url
http://java.oracle.com/


java.vm.info
mixed mode


Default diff key
Order is Descending, nulls sort First, approx numeric compared to 5 digits, no pad semantics, type compatibility is Comparable, epsilon 2.


user.dir
...


sun.cpu.isalist



java.awt.graphicsenv
sun.awt.CGraphicsEnvironment


sun.os.patch.level
unknown


typesdataResource
/configuration/datasets/types
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal but complete stylesheet that produces the result you posted?

Comment: And also, show a sample XML input document that produces this output.

Comment: Also, show which version of Saxon you are using (add -t to the command line).

Comment: Since your input document seems to be a test report created by Java, is it possible that this output you're seeing is part of the input document? Perhaps you have errors in your stylesheet.